# several resource rules are not properly recognized by maven eclipse:eclipse

Tags: maven, resources, include, pom.xml

I have a pom.xml with the following under `<build>`:

```
<resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
             <excludes>
             <!-- exclude binary files. They get corrupted by filtering -->
              <exclude>**/*.zip</exclude>
             </excludes>
        </resource>
        <!-- copy binary files separately without filtering. They get corrupted by filtering -->
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
                <includes>
                  <include>**/*.zip</include>
                </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

Now this works perfectly when I build a jar using maven install. It then excludes the zip files from filtering, but copies them separately whithout filtering.

However, when I do a maven eclipse:eclipse, I see in eclipse under (right click) `MyProject->Properties->Java Build Path->Source->MyProject/src/main/resources` that **/*.zip is excluded. So apparently only the first `<resource>` element in my pom is recognized.

I need both recognized, since I also need the zip file copied to targetEclipse when working in dev environment.

Any idea how to accomplish this?

The maven docu about eclipse:eclipse states:

> Invokes the execution of the lifecycle phase generate-resources prior to executing itself.

So regarding the resources it should just do the same as when I execute maven install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out myself...:
Apparently the eclipse:eclipse only allows one configuration per resource directory and ignores all others.
So I created a second resource directoryx, where I put all the binary files. I now only apply the filtering to the one containing no binary files. That way it works both with eclipse:eclipse and install:

```
<resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
        <!-- copy binary files separately without filtering. They get corrupted by filtering -->
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/bin</directory>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```